# pam_appl.h and pam_misc.h missing, in rshd.c source code

Tags: c, linux, centos, pam, rsh

I am working on a **centOS 5.5 OS**.

It shows error that /security/pam_appl.h and /security/misc.h file is missing.

Actually my rshd.c does not loads PAM module, may be by putting this libraries, it helps me to work my rshd fine. That's why I posted this question.

**Error:-**

```
rshd.c:90:31: error: security/pam_appl.h: No such file or directory
rshd.c:91:31: error: security/pam_misc.h: No such file or directory
```

I search a lot but didn't get any useful rpm that gives these files.

Some links are [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=/usr/include/security/pam_appl.h). But not suitable for centOS.

Help me. Tell me how can I overcome from this problem.

**Edit no 1**

Your third link seems useful. When I try to install pam-devel , it shows some error.

When I run

```bash
./configure --prefix=/usr \
            --sysconfdir=/etc \
            --docdir=/usr/share/doc/Linux-PAM-1.1.6 \
            --disable-nis &&
make
```

it checks for some variables , then it makes object file, but at the end it shows,

```
make[3]: *** [pam_xauth.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `~/Linux-PAM-1.1.6/modules/pam_xauth'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `~/Linux-PAM-1.1.6/modules'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `~/Linux-PAM-1.1.6'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Edit No. 2**

As I followed your command, it shows me below error, at the end.

This error came, when I run  `make && make install`

```
pam_xauth.c:64:27: error: selinux/label.h: No such file or directory
pam_xauth.c: In function âpam_sm_open_sessionâ:
pam_xauth.c:616: error: âSELABEL_CTX_FILEâ undeclared (first use in this function)
pam_xauth.c:616: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
pam_xauth.c:616: error: for each function it appears in.)
pam_xauth.c:616: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
make[3]: *** [pam_xauth.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Linux-PAM-1.1.6/modules/pam_xauth'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Linux-PAM-1.1.6/modules'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Linux-PAM-1.1.6'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Why do you think that these headers should exist? What are you trying to do?

Comment: rsh is not open and read pam modules and limits.conf. When I make `strace` of command `rrsh localhost ulimit -n`. It does not show any pam module file in `open` system call. It throws `1024`, but it is expected to throw `13000` as `/etc/security/limits.conf` contains `13000`. That's why I want to debug my code, and try to add these libraries.  I think, now you understand why I need these.

Comment: On your platform, if you search from root can you find those files? Is the path correct? (`stdinclude/security/xxx.h`)

Comment: stdinclude is not present.

Comment: @Mike Please solve this problem. I tried a lot but I am unable to load PAM in my function. Please see another question ,  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71783/how-can-i-add-pam-functionality-in-netkit-rsh-0-17

Comment: @bmargulies Please solve this problem. I tried a lot but I am unable to load PAM in my function. Please see another question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71783/how-can-i-add-pam-functionality-in-netkit-rsh-0-17

Comment: For those who got here by searching but are using Ubuntu: the package is `libpam0g-dev`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't have CentOS at the moment, but it seems like this is a common problem. See [here](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=38429) for information, it's suggested you install pam-devel so you don't have to build from source via:

```
yum install pam-devel
```

Seems everytime I find a [site](http://blog.alwayshere.info/2011/11/error-securitypamapplh-no-such-file-or.html) where the [problem](http://mailman2.u.washington.edu/pipermail/imap-uw/2009-December/002615.html) is the same as yours the fix is to install this. I'm downloading CentOS 5.5 to give it a try now, but did you just try running that command?

If you did install that and it's still not finding the header files I'd give this a try:

```
cd /
sudo find . -name "pam_appl.h"
sudo find . -name "pam_misc.h"
```

It's possible that they were installed and didn't go into your standard include path, or didn't go into the `security/` directory, in which case you'll need to either move them or change the way the header is included in your code.

**Note** for the `sudo` commands you'll have to enter your password.

Comment: I found the libraries. Thanks. :)
But my main problem is still there. Can we discuss via chat, please. I want to solve that.

Comment: @devsda - fire off some thoughts here, I'll open a room when I get back and we can talk. I have to go out for a few hours. Let me know what issues you have and I'll see if we can resolve them. Glad we found the files

Comment: And for Debian and derivatives, that would be `sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev`

Comment: All the links are now 404

Answer (score 23):

if someone is looking for debian/ubuntu, try this `sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev`

Answer (score 3):

You need the rpm for [pam-devel](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=/usr/include/security/pam_appl.h), available for CentOS [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=pam-devel&srodzaj=3&dist%5B%5D=55). Alternatively, you can download pam from [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/linux-pam.html) and install it locally.

**Edit:**
To compile it, this works fine on my system:

```bash
wget http://linux-pam.org/library/Linux-PAM-1.1.6.tar.bz2
tar xvjf Linux-PAM-1.1.6.tar.bz2
cd Linux-PAM-1.1.6/
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
make && make install
```

If it does not, please report the compiler errors.

Comment: Please check Edit no. 1, it shows the problem occurs during following your instructions.

Comment: First of all sorry for late reply. I fllowed your given instructed commands but it shows error while executing last command. See those error in Edit no. 2. Please.

Comment: search and install a package containing selinux-devel or selinux-dev in the name. Alternatively add the flag `--disable-selinux` to `./configure`, but that might have side effects.

Answer (score 1):

For people who find this through the search engines, the following worked for me on CentOS 7:

```
yum install pam-devel
```