# Extracting Riak "Example Servers" Chapter 2 of Seven Database in Seven Weeks

Tags: riak

I recently started reading 7 databases in 7 weeks to try to broaden expand my knowledge.  I have been stuck at the beginning of the first RIAK chapter for awhile.  I'm trying to figure out how to extract the example servers from the source since i have installed the binaries on Ubuntu.  The first commands that I'm supposed to run use the example servers:

```
dev/dev1/bin/riak start
dev/dev2/bin/riak start
dev/dev3/bin/riak start
```

When I look in the source I don't see anything that appears to be this so not really sure what I'm looking for.

Officially the authors wanted me to build RIAK but they are using 1.0.2 which I couldn't find a version of Erlang to build.  I also tried building the latest and I ran into this:

```
snappy-test.cc: At global scope:
snappy-test.cc:82:15: error: aggregate ‘snappy::rusage       
snappy::benchmark_start_cpu’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined 
struct rusage benchmark_start_cpu;
```

Edit the version of the binaries I installed is:

```
riak version
2.1.1
```

I also have the source files for 1.0.2 and the latest version of trunk from Github from 6/5/2015 Probably like 10pm.

Comment: So which version of Riak are you trying out?

Comment: I have R16B03 installed (without the basho patches, bad?), got the source with `git clone -b 2.1.1 https://github.com/basho/riak riak`, then `cd riak; make devrel`.  This created the dev/devN directories with the example servers.

Comment: @Joe I am getting this error canola-port.c:36:31: fatal error: security/pam_appl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <security/pam_appl.h>
Seems I need to install pam-devel but I can't seem to find it for Ubuntu are you running Ubuntu?

Comment: currently trying this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15901819/1757491

Comment: I believe the Ubuntu package is [libpam0g](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libpam0g)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the directions for the book, but I know it's out of date for building Riak KV. The latest how-to for Ubuntu is [kept up-to-date here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/debian-ubuntu/).

A few tips:

- You can find wherever Riak KV is running by hunting down the `beam` process: `ps aux | grep beam`
- If you want to download any pre-built package by Basho, you can [find them on PackageCloud](https://packagecloud.io/basho)

If your goal is to get to playing around with Riak in a real-to-world way, installing from PackageCloud is what we do.

Comment: Using this I was able to get 1 riak server running.  The first part of the book wants you to make 3 servers on the local machine but it sounds like without building from source this is tough to do.

Comment: curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8087/ping
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8087 (#0)
> GET /ping HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8087
> Accept: */*
> 
^C
The book was expecting a response of OK

Answer (score 1):

Another way is running Riak (KV) in Docker:

`docker run -it --rm -e CLUSTER_NAME=riakkv basho/riak-kv`

Additional nodes will need to know the `COORDINATOR_NODE`.

A full cluster can be simulated in Docker Compose. See this example from:

https://hub.docker.com/r/basho/riak-kv/

```
version: "2"
services:
  coordinator:
    image: basho/riak-kv
    ports:
      - "8087:8087"
      - "8098:8098"
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=riakkv
    labels:
      - "com.basho.riak.cluster.name=riakkv"
    volumes:
      - schemas:/etc/riak/schemas
  member:
    image: basho/riak-kv
    ports:
      - "8087"
      - "8098"
    labels:
      - "com.basho.riak.cluster.name=riakkv"
    links:
      - coordinator
    depends_on:
      - coordinator
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=riakkv
      - COORDINATOR_NODE=coordinator

volumes:
  schemas:
    external: false
```

I was struggling to find ready to use examples myself, so people reaching this post might be interested in [this repo with Docker Compose examples](https://github.com/turiphro/NoSQLlab/tree/master/riak) that I created, including scripts and example data.